# Symfony общая папка uploads для нескольких проектов

Tags: fileupload, symfony3

Есть небольшой фронтэнд и небольшая админка на symfony (два проекта). Будут находиться на одном сервере. Админка на поддомене.
В symfony админке используется:

- ckeditor-bundle как визульный редактор
- fm-elfinder-bundle для аплоада изображений на сервер.

**app/config/config.yml**

```
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, fm_tinymce, form, simple, custom
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to manage loading of javascript and css assets manually
            connector:
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined, defines root filemanager directories
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 4M
```

Т.е. в админке можно создать страницы и загрузить изображения на данный момент в:
/path/admin/web/uploads

А у фронтэнда свой server root:
/path/front/web.

Как лучше всего сделать загруженные изображения общими для двух проектов, чтобы фронт их читал?

На данный момент есть вариант с симлинком:

```
ln -s /path/admin/web/uploads /path/front/web/uploads
```

Первый мой проект на symfony. Хотел узнать, какой наиболее правильный путь сделать изображения общими?

Comment: А как насчёт указать в обеих проектах путь к одной и той же папке ?

Comment: @ВадимБондаренко вроде и альтернатива `path: /tmp/uploads` можно задать абсолютным. Но все равно есть нюанс, т.к. путь должен быть "внутри" document root сервера (для двух проектов), чтобы картинки отдавались как статика и были видны и там и там. При варианте /tmp/uploads картинки не отдаются даже в админке после загрузки, т.к. docRoot админки /path/admin/web/ (хотя конечно на диске картинки есть).